# Crystal Reports, Sum of DateTime field, and group by User

Tags: crystal-reports, sum

I want to calculate sum of field (DateTime) in Crystal Reports , and for each group.

When i right click in field then Insert->Smmary ,in this window i can select group and it is ok. Also I can select Summary (Minimum, Maximum,Count...) BUT no SUM , why?

Comment: And what is your expected result of adding say July, 7th 2010 and August, 30th 2009?

Comment: Thanks for reply , oh sorry  i forget to say , field have this complexion-    xx:хх   (hours-minutes) , and for example 22:48 + 9:03=31:51

Comment: Field type is string, may need to write formula, that converts it to numbers and calculate sum ? problem is i do not know CR formulas :(

Comment: Your claims are contradicting - in posting you talk about DateTime, in comments about String. Well, CR behavior points to DateTime anyway :) You can start with formula like Mark Bannister wrote; maybe avoiding seconds part. Well, to get output in form HH:MM, you of course need another formula to format output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason (as Arvo implies) is that there is no sense in which datetimes can be added to each other.

You can create a crystal formula to derive the number of seconds since midnight in a datetime field - this would look like:

```
Hour ({MyTable.MyDate}) * 3600 + 
Minute ({MyTable.MyDate}) * 60 + 
Second ({MyTable.MyDate})
```

(Crystal's DateTime functions can be found in the Function Tree in the Formula Editor dialog, under the Date and Time option.)

The formula field could then be SUMmed like any other numeric field - the result would be expressed in seconds.

EDIT:

Assuming there are no padding characters in l1, a formula item with the expression:

```
ToNumber (Left (DefaultReportPlugin_DetailedDailyReport_ReportData.I1, 2)) * 60 +
ToNumber (Right (DefaultReportPlugin_DetailedDailyReport_ReportData.I1, 2))
```

would convert the string to a number expressed in minutes. (The Left, Right and ToNumber fields can be found under the Strings option in the Function Tree in the Formula Editor dialog.)

A sum of the formula (expressed in minutes) can be displayed by inserting the formula item into the report, right-clicking on it and selecting the `Insert > Summary...` option from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Thanks!!! I get string data as DateTime then Hours or Minutes, BUT i can not do SUM, because SUM fuction wants fild as argument:And DateTime gives only last row, and i can not claculate SUM :(((        Hour (DateTime({DefaultReportPlugin_DetailedDailyReport_ReportData.I1})) * 60 + Minute (DateTime({DefaultReportPlugin_DetailedDailyReport_ReportData.I1}))

Comment: @Armen Khachatryan: is l1 a datetime field, or a string containing datetime-formatted values? If it is the latter, please can you indicate how it is formatted (eg. dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi).

Comment: Type of I1 is string, and string write in this format hh:mm , all i need to convert that strings to NUMBER (as you write) and then SUM.

Comment: very good!!!, and one last question, what if in any rosw there are no data, (string "" ) , in this case -ERROR :(

Comment: OK, i solve this. One other question, I want result to be in this format hh:mm , how can i do this? Have function ToTimeSpan in stead of ToNumber.  ?

Comment: @Armen Khachatryan, the simplest way would be to setup *another* Crystal formula in the format `ToText (Truncate (Sum ({@NumTime})/60)) + ":" + ToText (Remainder (Sum ({@NumTime}), 60))`, to show the result as a grand total. (To show the result by group, change `Sum ({@NumTime})` in the formula to `Sum ({@NumTime}, {Table.GroupItem})`.)

Comment: It' a wonderful , and now results are in this format  23,00 :56,00 , i do not want to show ,00 ...   ?

Comment: Add `, 0` (the number of decimal places) as a new argument to the ToText function in the formula, like so: `ToText (Truncate (Sum ({@NumTime})/60), 0) + ":" + ToText (Remainder (Sum ({@NumTime}), 60), 0)`

Comment: ALL is ok, Thank yo very much!